# Updating style on runtime in wpf

Tags: wpf, user-interface, xaml, styles

I have a style for a ItemContainer that is based on the Item being contained (With a StyleSelector). It works fine. However on runtime the property might be changed but the style isn't updated instantly.

Is there anyway for me to get it to update as soon as the changes are saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DataTrigger and a Converter which returns the Type of an object

For example,

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter=ObjectToTypeConverter}" 
                 Value="{x:Type local:Person}">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{Binding PersonTemplate}" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter=ObjectToTypeConverter}" 
                 Value="{x:Type local:Business}">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{Binding BusinessTemplate}" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: Here you will be changing the DataTemplate of the item right? I wan't to change the ItemContainerTemplate. I have no access to the DataTemplate as it will be set through a dependency property at the time of the controls creation.

Comment: Can I actually bind to the object contained inside a ItemContainerStyle? If yes then this could actually work.

Comment: Much to my surprise I could just bind to the assumed object inside the ItemContainersControlTemplate and it works just fine.

Comment: @Ingo Sure, you could change the ItemContainerTemplate instead of the DataTemplate. I wasn't sure how your XAML looked so wrote it this way as an example

Answer (score 1):

Use binding. Then you will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  The value you are setting should be a property and at the end of the setter, raise the property changed event.

If you give an example of your XAML, I can write it out for you.

Comment: Problem is I ain't binding. I'm using a ItemContainerStyleSelector inside a ListBox. I'm not sure I can bind as the objects in the list can be of various types and they may not have the property I'm basing my style on. This is something I check in the styleSelector.